# Generate C# from WSDL, without "Order"

Tags: c#, .net, xmlserializer, xsd.exe, service-reference

I generate C# code from WSDL using "Service References" in Visual C# 2010 (see screenshot).

Generated code uses `Order` parameters, which makes me think that under the hood, Visual C# is performing is running `xsd.exe /order`, among other things. Example:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=1)]
```

Because of a [Mono bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2907), I want to generate C# code WITHOUT `Order` parameters.
To do that with `xsd.exe` (XSD to C#), I would simply omit the `/order` parameter.

But how to generate `Order`-free code from a WSDL file?
Only the following settings seem to be available:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

generate the code normally, then do a regex search and replace in VS.
Replace all occurances of (Order=*)] with ]

Comment: Thanks! I now replaced like you said. Using `/order` also inserts `[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=1)]` and similar lines, that are not present when not using `/order`. So I guess I should remove those lines?

Comment: Yes, I can't think of anything else at the moment :)
But are those lines also causing problem with your MONO code ?

Comment: i meant what is the generated code, a proxy for the service ?

Comment: The generated code contains C# methods that allow me to call the web service.

Comment: I am testing now, I think it works, thanks a lot! I will do a bit more testing and then accept your answer :-)